# Need help parsing a string in php

Tags: php, json, string

Hello I am trying to process and read/parse data from a string in PHP. The string when var dumped looks like this

```
 string(266) "{ "address": { "address_line1": "2391 US HIGHWAY 22 W", "address_line2": "", "address_city": "UNION", "address_state": "NJ", "address_zip": "07083-8517", "address_country": "US", "object": "address" } }"
```

I would like to be able to store

`address_line1`, `address_line2`, `address_city`, `address_state`, `address_zip` and `address_country` into variables so I can manipulate them as I please.

How do I go about doing this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you have stringified json and you want to get the values out?

Comment: @CleoR the OP is using PHP, not Python

Comment: Complete oversight on my part. The Ps got me mixed up haha. I'm sure the question/answer exists for PHP already.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `json_decode()` function to retrieve your data:

```
$input = '{ "address": { "address_line1": "2391 US HIGHWAY 22 W", "address_line2": "", "address_city": "UNION", "address_state": "NJ", "address_zip": "07083-8517", "address_country": "US", "object": "address" } }';
$result = json_decode($input, true);

var_dump($result); // see whole array

echo $result['address']['address_line1']; // specific data
```

More information you can get from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to JSON using the following instruction

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Then you can get the values from the JSON as below

```
$obj->address->address_line1;
```